# Sub inside a loop stops loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to get a sub to run inside a loop in another sub, but sadly it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
Sub PrintSet()

Level = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("MARKUP PLAN").Range("m2:m100"))

Dim Lvl As String

For i = 0 To Level - 1

Lvl = Worksheets("MARKUP PLAN").Cells(i + 2, 13).Value
Worksheets("MARKUP PLAN").Cells(10, 32).Value = Lvl

ChartUpdatePlan 'Run Chart sub to update the chart on sheet "MARKUP PLAN"

Worksheets("MARKUP PLAN").Range("a2:AF37").Select
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Lvl & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True

Next i

End Sub
```

When I run it, it prints the very first level (i=0) then stops without any reason (or at least none that I can find).

When I get rid of the loop and manually increment "Lvl", it works fine, but of course I'd rather not have to do that manually.

If i get rid of the "ChartUpdatePlan" sub in the loop, the loop works just fine and every level is printed, but the chart does not get updated.

Can anyone tell me why the loop doesn't work when the sub is called but works when it's not?

Thank you very much,
Antoine

Comment: First thing I'd try would be to rename your `Chart` sub - that collides with the name of an Excel object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Cominter. I changed the name of the sub to "ChartUpdatePlan", sadly it didn't resolve my issue.

Comment: Try step-through with F8 so you can see the exact step that's making it die.  Please also post your code for `ChartUpdatePlan`

Comment: Where do you have your variable `Level` declared? I'm asking, because you most likely declared it in some other procedure, which is not conflicting with your code's scope

Comment: FWIW the loop isn't the source of your error.

Comment: @n8., when I step-through with F8 it runs through the entire ChartUpdatePlanChart sub correctly, it runs through the printing part and then goes straight from "next i" to "end sub", as if it was at the last value of i.

Comment: @Rawrplus, Level is declared above the sub, (dim Level as Integer), and has a 
value of 7 when i use debug.print Level. It is not used in the ChartUpdatePlan sub.

Comment: SOLVED: i was  used in the ChartUpdatePlan, and although it didn't create an error when I ran my code, I'm guessing the value of i at the end of ChartUpdatePlan is greater than the value of Level, causing the loop to end.

Comment: F8 is your friend.  Not as good as n8 but still great.

Comment: I actually didn't know about F8 before that, thanks for the info @n8.

Comment: step-through ftw

Comment: I rolled back your edit. It's not appropriate here to add *SOLVED* to the title or to add a solution to your question. If you've found a solution you'd like to share, use the space below for *Your Answer* to do so. It's acceptable to answer your own question, but it has to be done properly. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information about how to do so.